# How to get a constant offset of Adorner in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add drag and drop as a feature to my program. However I am really close at getting it right, but I can't figure out how to set a constant offset of the Adorner I built. It has a way to big offset and as I move the mouse it even changes.
I create the adorner within the following method:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
    Vector diff = _startPoint.Value - mousePos;

    // Initialize the drag & drop operation
    DataObject dragData = new DataObject("foo", foo);
    _adorner = new DragAdorner(button, mousePos);
    AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this).Add(_adorner);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
    if (_adorner != null && AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(button) != null)
        AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this).Remove(_adorner);
}
```

I update the Position with another method:

```
private void OnGiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (_adorner == null) return;

    UIElement lbl = sender as UIElement;
    if (lbl == null) return;

    var pos = lbl.PointToScreen(Utils.GetCursorPos());
    _adorner.UpdatePosition(pos);
}
```

And the DragAdorner.cs looks like this:

```
public class DragAdorner : Adorner
{
    private Brush _vbrush;
    private Point _location;
    private Point _offset;

    public DragAdorner(UIElement adornedElement, Point offset)

        : base(adornedElement)
    {

        _offset = offset;
        IsHitTestVisible = false;
        _vbrush = new VisualBrush(AdornedElement) {Opacity = .7};
    }

    public void UpdatePosition(Point location)
    {
        _location = location;
        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    public void SetDropable(bool dropable)
    {
        ReservationButton button = AdornedElement as ReservationButton;
        if (button == null) return;

        if (dropable)
        {
            button.Background = Utils.GetReservationColor(button.Reservation.Status);
        }
        else
        {
            button.Background = NaramisColors.Yellow;
        } 
        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {

        var p = _location;

        p.Offset(-_offset.X, -_offset.Y);

        dc.DrawRectangle(_vbrush, null, new Rect(p, RenderSize));
    }
}
```

Inside of Utils.cs I wrote the methods to get a Win32Point

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public POINT(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

private static Point ConvertPixelsToUnits(int x, int y)
{
    // get the system DPI
    IntPtr dDc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero); // Get desktop DC
    int dpi = GetDeviceCaps(dDc, 88);
    bool rv = ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, dDc);

    // WPF's physical unit size is calculated by taking the 
    // "Device-Independant Unit Size" (always 1/96)
    // and scaling it by the system DPI
    double physicalUnitSize = 1d / 96d * dpi;
    Point wpfUnits = new Point(x / physicalUnitSize ,  y / physicalUnitSize);

    return wpfUnits;
}

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);
public enum DeviceCap
{
    VERTRES = 10,
    DESKTOPVERTRES = 117

}

public static float GetScalingFactor()
{
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
    IntPtr desktop = g.GetHdc();
    int logicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.VERTRES);
    int physicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(desktop, (int)DeviceCap.DESKTOPVERTRES);

    float screenScalingFactor = physicalScreenHeight / (float)logicalScreenHeight;

    return screenScalingFactor; // 1.25 = 125%
}

public static Point GetCursorPos()
{
    POINT p;
    if (GetCursorPos(out p))
    {
        Point wpfPoint = ConvertPixelsToUnits(p.X, p.Y);
        return wpfPoint;
    }
    return new Point();
}
```

Also I made a gif to visualize my problem, you can find it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kGJu.jpg)

I'd be really happy if you could help me out with this one, I am working on it for hours now and I just can't find the right solution.

Comment: Is it ok that you use `mousePos` as offset? I see that `diff` variable is not used so I suppose you want to use `X`, `Y`, or `Length` of `diff` as offset.

Comment: @Maxim Well no, diff is just used to specify if the mouse has moved. But I did try it and it did not work

Comment: I have implemented a similar Adorner, and update its position via ArrangeOverride() in the DragAdorner class, e.g. `button.Arrange(new Rect((desiredWidth - adornerWidth), -adornerHeight, adornerWidth, adornerHeight));` where the desired width/height is the RenderSize of the AdornedElement and the adorner Width/Height is the RenderSize of the adorner itself. That "just works" without any special offset compensation logic.

Comment: @Lennart Gotta try that, I kind of fixed it now by replacing `lbl.PointToScreen(Utils.GetCursorPos());` with `lbl.TransaltePoint(Utils.GetCursorPos(), _dragsource);` and I then hardcoded the offset in the adorner. Not the best solution but it works for now.

Comment: I found a similar implementation of mine at https://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/ which has a more complete example. Check their ArrangeOverride method, should be roughly the same you need.